# How do I configure Emacs to autosave and backup to dotfiles?

Tags: emacs

I'd like to configure Emacs so that it autosaves and creates backups to a dotfile in the same directory as the file I'm editing (similar to Vim's `.sw*` files).

For example, when I'm editing `foo.py`, I'd like the autosave file to be `.foo.py#`, and the backup file to be `.foo.py~`.

How can I do that?

I've tried adding an item to `auto-save-file-name-transforms`: `("(.*/)?(.*)" ".\\2.swx" t)`, but that didn't seem to work (autosave files with the name `#file#` were still being created; nb: I added it using `M-x customize-variable`, so I don't think it was a syntax error or something trivial).

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour for Emacs's regexes is to match parentheses as parentheses. You'll need to escape them to do group captures. Try this:

```
("\\(.*/\\)?\\(.*\\)" ".\\2.swx" t)
```